# error specification of OLS regression models

Tags: econometrics, regression, statistics

Consider the following regression equation * \begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
C_{t} = \beta_{1} + \lambda   C_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}
\end{equation}
and let \begin{equation} \label{eq:3}
\epsilon_{t} = \rho\epsilon_{t-1} + u_{t}
\end{equation} where the error component \begin{equation} u_{t}\end{equation} is iid with mean 0 and constant
variance, and \begin{equation} \label{eq:4}
E(u_{t}\mid   C_{t-1},\epsilon_{t-1}) = 0
\end{equation}
Is the OLS estimator of the coefficients in (*)
unbiased and consistent under this error specification? Why?

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of OLS estimator we can rewrite the $\hat\lambda$ as
$\hat\lambda=argmin \sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_t^2$
From first order condition, we get $\hat\lambda=\frac{\sum_{i}^{n}(C_{t-1}-\bar{C}_{t-1})(C_t-\bar{C_t} )}{\sum_{i}^{n}(C_{t-1}-\bar{C}_{t-1})^2} $
You can get more simple expression as $\hat\lambda=\lambda+\frac{\sum_{i}^{n}(C_{t-1}-\bar{C}_{t-1})(\epsilon_t-\bar{\epsilon_t})}{\sum_{i}^{n}(C_{t-1}-\bar{C}_{t-1})^2}$
Since $E[(C_{t-1}-\bar{C}_{t-1})(\epsilon_t-\bar{\epsilon_t})]=0$, $E(\hat\lambda)=\lambda$.(unbiased)

Now apply Law of Large Numbers to show consistency.

$\hat\lambda =\frac{\sum_{i}^{n}(C_{t-1}-\bar{C}_{t-1})(C_t-\bar{C_t} )}{\sum_{i}^{n}(C_{t-1}-\bar{C}_{t-1})^2}=\frac{1/n\sum_{i}^{n}(C_{t-1}-\bar{C}_{t-1})(C_t-\bar{C_t} )}{1/n\sum_{i}^{n}(C_{t-1}-\bar{C}_{t-1})^2}$
By LLN, $\hat\lambda =\frac{Cov(C_t, C_t-1)}{Var(C_t-1)}=\frac{Cov(\beta_1 +\lambda C_t-1 +\epsilon_t, C_t-1)}{Var(C_t-1)}=\frac{\lambda Var(C_t-1)+Cov(\epsilon_t, C_t-1)}{Var(C_t-1)}=\lambda $.(consistent)

Comment: what does lln mean?

Comment: @JohnWilliams LLN means Law of Large Numbers

Comment: could you explain why its unbiased and consistent with more words?

Comment: @JohnWilliams I edited my solution. You need to know the concept of LLN to prove consistency.

Comment: The AR(1) is not unbiased for the lagged coefficient even in the case where the error term is purely iid. See this link for a couple of different and insightful explanations. The link doesn't cover  whether it's consistent for the AR(1) error term case but I don't think it is. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240383/why-is-ols-estimator-of-ar1-coefficient-biased